# Calling a function multiple times consecutively with different arguments in Python (3.x)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, shortcut

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
myfunction(a, b, c)
myfunction(d, e, f)
myfunction(g, h, i)
myfunction(j, k, l)
```

The number of arguments do not change, but the function has to be called consecutively with different values each time. These values are not automatically generated and are manually inputted. Is there an inline solution to do this without creating a function to call this function? Something like:

```
myfunction(a, b, c)(d, e f)(g, h, i)(j, k, l)
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are wanting to achieve. Do you want to call the function only once with all the possible values?

Comment: Do you want to use the results of calling the function as arguments to the next call of the same function?

Comment: You can do `a, b, c = input().split(' ')` in a while True kind of loop and then call class `myfunction(a, b, c)`

Comment: Can you give a sample implementation? No one seems to know exactly what you want to do. What does `myfunction` take and return?

Comment: @Adam Creates a dictionary key named a, appends value b for number of times c. But not really relevant imo, basically a short way to call same function with different arguments instead of having to manually type it each time.

Comment: @RottenCandy No, call the function multiple times, each time with a different set of values as arguments.

Comment: @salaparadise Nope, The arguments are mutually exclusive and manually inputted, like it says in the question :) I just want a shorter way to call the same function several times with different sets of arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple, use tuple unpacking

```
tripples = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i'), ('j', 'k', 'm')]
for tripple in tripples:
    print(myfunction(*tripple))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that nobody mentioned [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

```
map(func, iter)
```

It maps each iterable in `iter` to the `func` passed in the first argument.

For your use case it should look like

```
map(myfunction, *zip((a, b, c), (d, e, f), (g, h, i), (j, k, l)))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work: The four tuples are interpreted as four parameters, so it fails with `TypeError: myfunction() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`. Better use the same with `map(myfunction, *zip( (a, b, c), ... ))`.

Comment: I don't think this works the way you imagine.
>>> print(*zip((1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12)))
(1, 4, 7, 10) (2, 5, 8, 11) (3, 6, 9, 12)
>>> print(*((1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12)))
(1, 2, 3) (4, 5, 6) (7, 8, 9) (10, 11, 12)

Answer (score 1):

You can misuse list comprehension here

```
[myfunction(*item) for item in ((a, b, c), (d, e, f), (g, h, i), (j, k, l))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not sure whether it's the most pythonic way , but if you have arguments defined as in a list the you can call the function in a loop, and remove the n argument from the beginning of the list :

Have a look to the sample code :

```
def myfunction(x1,x2,x3):
    return x1+x2+x3


arglist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for _ in range(3):
    print  myfunction(arglist[_+0],arglist[_+1],arglist[_+2])
    # remove used arguments from the list 
    arglist= arglist[2:]
```

Comment: It's an interesting alternative to simply calling a function multiple times, true, but it seems more convoluted a way to go about than the accepted answer. This is also viable though.

Comment: @Terrornado : 100% agree with you , even though it servers the purpose , packing unpacking concept is better approach

Comment: the `_` symbol indicates that the value will never be used. Maybe use `i` instead?

Comment: @AdamSmith : both has the same meaning , _ also represents a variable , _ or i doesn't matters

Comment: I don't understand why people down vote even if answer is correct , might not be the best but it serves the purpose

Comment: @csharpcoder `_` has no special meaning in Python, but it does to a Python programmer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python and please stop using it as you have -- you're making the job of whoever has to maintain your code much harder than it needs to be. `_` or `i` most definitely *does* matter.

Comment: @csharpcoder and you earned my downvote because I don't believe your answer is useful. Advising indexing a list, even if you used the right loop variable name, over iterating over triples is, well, inadvisable. Note also that your code as-written has a hastily-written typo, and fails on a `NameError`.

Comment: instead of removing first two, we can use: arglist[3*i], arglist[3*i+1], arglist[3*i+2]

Answer (score -3):

I think what you want to do is something like this...

```
myfunction(myfunction(d, e, f), myfunction(g, h, i), myfunction(j, k, l))
```